# Why doesn't net/http respect timeout durations longer than 30 seconds?

Tags: go

Using golang 1.20.1.

In golang's net/http and context packages, I'm unable to set a timeout longer than thirty seconds. Setting a shorter timeout works fine, e.g.

Code:

```
    log.Infof("Elasticsearch URL is %v", elasticsearchURL)
    client := &http.Client{Timeout: time.Duration(time.Second * 60)}
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", listBackupsURL, nil)
    if err != nil {
        internalError(w, fmt.Sprintf("error creating request: %v", err))
        return
    }
    req.SetBasicAuth(username, password)
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        // handle error
        internalError(w, fmt.Sprintf("error accessing elasticsearch: %v", err))
        return
    }
```

Logs:

```
I0503 23:01:55.973821       1 somecode.go:85] URL is http://elasticsearch.example.ingest:9200
E0503 23:02:25.976345       1 caller_handler.go:63] 500 Internal Server Error: error accessing elasticsearch: Get "http://elasticsearch.example.ingest:9200/_cat/snapshots/object-store-repo?v&s=id": dial tcp 1.2.3.4:9200: i/o timeout
```

The timeout is thirty seconds, not sixty.

I get the same behavior if I use `http.NewRequestWithContext(...)` and use a context setting the same timeouts:

Code:

```
    log.Infof("Elasticsearch URL is %v", elasticsearchURL)
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Duration(time.Second * 60)) 
    defer cancel()
    req, err := http.NewRequestWithContext(ctx, "GET", listBackupsURL, nil)
    if err != nil {
        internalError(w, fmt.Sprintf("error creating request: %v", err))
        return
    }
    req.SetBasicAuth(username, password)
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        // handle error
        internalError(w, fmt.Sprintf("error accessing elasticsearch: %v", err))
        return
    }
```

Logs:

```
I0503 23:31:10.941169       1 somecode.go:85] Elasticsearch URL is http://elasticsearch.example.ingest:9200
E0503 23:31:40.941642       1 caller_handler.go:63] 500 Internal Server Error: error accessing elasticsearch: Get "http://elasticsearch.example.ingest:9200/_cat/snapshots/object-store-repo?v&s=id": dial tcp 1.2.3.4:9200: i/o timeout
```

However, if I change the timeout to three seconds (`time.Duration(time.Second * 3))` in either method, it works as expected:

```
I0503 23:44:17.622121       1 somecode.go:85] Elasticsearch URL is http://elasticsearch.example.ingest:9200
E0503 23:44:20.624795       1 caller_handler.go:63] 500 Internal Server Error: error accessing elasticsearch: Get "http://elasticsearch.example.ingest:9200/_cat/snapshots/object-store-repo?v&s=id": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

Comment: I think you're hitting a default dial timeout .  https://blog.cloudflare.com/the-complete-guide-to-golang-net-http-timeouts/ talks about how you can set the http.Client's transport to configure a Dial timeout.  If you're getting a timeout dialing though, you probably can't reach the machine for some reason.

Comment: Setting the overall timeout longer isn't going to change individual timeouts. But like erik258 said, if you can't connect in 30 seconds, a longer timeout is probably not going to help.

Comment: In Go's net/http and context packages, setting a timeout longer than 30 seconds is limited by the default operating system TCP timeout. This is because Go's net/http package uses the underlying operating system's TCP timeout mechanism to implement timeouts.

You can override the default timeout by setting the Timeout field of the http.Client struct, as you are already doing. However, this will only work up to a certain point, which is determined by the operating system's TCP timeout.

Comment: In your case, the error message suggests that the timeout occurred exactly after 30 seconds, which is consistent with the default operating system TCP timeout.

Comment: If you need to set a longer timeout, you can try increasing the operating system's TCP timeout by using a tool such as sysctl (on Unix-like systems). For example, you could try:
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=300 This sets the operating system TCP timeout to 5 minutes (300 seconds). Note that this change will affect the entire operating system, not just your Go program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd isolate the problem to eliminate possibilities to help narrow what is causing it to happen. If possible, use a small piece of code so you deal with only what you want.

To test your infrastructure [httpstat](https://httpstat.us) will help you simulate a remote timeout. Example:

```golang
func main() {

    client := &http.Client{Timeout: time.Duration(time.Second * 200)}
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://httpstat.us/504?sleep=120000", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(resp)
}
```

If you're getting `dial tcp IP:PORT: i/o timeout` timeout at this point, then you need to check your OS and and the firewall(s). Whatever timeout you set in Go should override the OS defaults, and if you're getting timeout in that way it is possible that there is a firewall (local or remote) causing that.

Alternatively, if you're able to connect externally, then there is a possibility that ES is timing out, although according to the docs you should expect an informative error coming from ES directly. You can se the timeout for ES [directly in the URL](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-search.html) and test it as well.

Hope this helps.